# Is it ok to abuse webview?

Tags: android

With webview you can make a layout using plain html, posing that you do not need to alter anything by code is it ok to just use webview?Overall performances are the same of native component or decrease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but the general experience will be less smoother that with native controls.

Alternatively, you can use tools that do this for you, which gives you more support over this kind of mobile development, and sometimes also native controls and features, exposed in a javascripts object, which can be pretty handy

Here are some examples :

- Phonegap : http://phonegap.com/
- trigger.io : http://trigger.io
- Tutanium Appcelerator : http://www.appcelerator.com/
  -

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. That is how phonegap or titanium is used to create their applications.

have a look at those. the entire apps made with those frameworks are viewed by a single webview inside an application. Basically the app is a website being used on your phone packed as an apk.